# Why can't the FILE pointer can't read the contents in the file?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I'm trying to get the contents from the file yh.dat which HAS the text like "456 78921" and somthing else by C.But when I try debug the code,the FILE pointer isn't NULL(0x00428af8) and the _ptr and the _base is NULL(0x000000).They says "CXX0030:Error:expression cannot be evaluated".How to solve it?

```
int main(){
   FILE *fp=NULL;
   fp=fopen("yh.dat","rb");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
        printf("error");
    exit(0);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question "How to solve it" implies that there's a problem.  The contents of a `FILE` object are unspecified, and vary from one implementation to another.  If operations on `fp` work as they're supposed to, there's no reason to worry about `fp->_ptr` *et al* (other than idle curiosity, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow you to change the file buffering, C doesn't set up the buffer for a file until you issue the first read. As such, until you attempt at least one read, it's normal for the members of whatever struct the FILE * points at to be in an only semi-initialized state.

Have you tried just reading data to see if it works?

Comment: yeah I've tried.  while(!feof(fp))
 {
  fscanf(fp,"%d",num);
printf("%d",num);    but it didn't print anything.
 }

Comment: You're passing the *value* of `num` to `fscanf`. What's it supposed to do with that?

Comment: @NobToJuneau: It won't stop you from reading at least something, but `while (!feof(whatever))` is essentially always wrong. I'd try something simple, like: `int ch; while ((ch=getc(fp) != EOF) putchar(ch);`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sorry i forget the & before num

Comment: That code assumes that `feof` can predict the future and tell you that your subsequent read will fail and therefore you shouldn't do it. That's not how `feof` works.

Comment: @JerryCoffin  THX  but one of my friends are working some codes and have the same problem.The similiar codes of mine in another profile seems to be good.It's strange...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You mean I should try another sentence like something Jerry said?

Comment: @NobToJuneau: If you have code that's not working, you can post it as a question. But the code you pasted here seems fine. You can do what Jerry said. The thing to remember is that `feof` can't predict the future. It can only tell you about what's already happened.

Comment: @NobToJuneau Also, a perror(0) over printf("error") is mostly a bit more informative. Also ferror() can be utilized.